# Copy a Parse.com class to new class with transformation of values

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, each

There is an existing Parse.com class that needs to be copied to a new Parse.com class with some new columns and the transformation of one of the columns. The code currently works and uses the Parse.Query.each method to iterate over all records as detailed in the Parse.com documentation but it stops processing at 831 records although there are 12k+ records in the class. This is odd given each should not have a limit and other default limits are 100 or 1000 for find.  Should another method be used to iterate over all records or is there something wrong with the code?

```
var SourceObject = Parse.Object.extend("Log_Old_Class");
var source_query = new Parse.Query(SourceObject);
var TargetObject = Parse.Object.extend("Log_New_Class")

source_query.each(function(record) {
    //save record to new class code works fine
    var target_query = new TargetObject();
    target_query.set("col1_new",record.col1);
    target_query.set("col2_new",record.col2);
    //etc...

    target_query.save(null, {
        success: function(obj) {
            //SAVED
        },
        error: function(obj, error) {
            //ERROR
        }
    });

}).then(function() {
    //DONE
},
function(error) {
    //error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to my mind immediately is that the function is getting timed-out. Parse has time limitations on each function. If I were you, I'd first load all the objects in the source class and then add them separately by having a delay between to API calls (server overload issues can also be present).